# Volley doesn't work with Gradle 2.0 and Instant run

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-volley, instant-run

I've recently updated Android Studio to version 2.0 : Beta 7.
I'm trying to use Instant Run, I've just installed Gradle 2.0.
But now I can't compile my project due to an error related to bintray.gradle

When I compile I get the following error :

```
Error:Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.
```

Debugger Error :

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Project\AtkApp\volley\bintray.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Cannot configure the 'publishing' extension after it has been accessed.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Bintray.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2"
    }
}

// apply the plugin with its class name rather than its Id to work around gradle limitation of
// not being able to find the plugin by Id despite the dependencies being added right above. Gradle
// is currently not capable of loading plugins by Id if the dependency is anywhere else than
// in the main project build.gradle. This file is "imported" into the project's build.gradle
// through a "apply from:".
apply plugin: com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayPlugin
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

project.ext.group = 'com.android.volley'
project.ext.archivesBaseName = 'volley'
project.ext.version = '1.0.0'
project.ext.pomDesc = 'Volley Android library'

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        library(MavenPublication) {
            groupId project.ext.group
            artifactId project.ext.archivesBaseName
            version project.ext.version

            // Release AAR, Sources, and JavaDoc
            artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/volley-release.aar"
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = System.env.BINTRAY_USER
    key = System.env.BINTRAY_USER_KEY

    publications = [ 'library' ]

    publish = project.has("release")
    pkg {
        userOrg = 'android'
        repo = 'android-utils'
        group = project.ext.group
        name = project.ext.group + '.' + project.ext.archivesBaseName
        desc = project.ext.pomDesc
        licenses = [ 'Apache-2.0' ]
        websiteUrl = 'https://tools.android.com'
        issueTrackerUrl = 'https://code.google.com/p/android/'
        vcsUrl = 'https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley.git'
        labels = ['android', 'volley', 'network']
        publicDownloadNumbers = true

        version {
            name = project.ext.version
            desc = project.ext.pomDesc + ' version ' + project.ext.version
            gpg {
                sign = true
                passphrase = System.env.GPG_PASSPHRASE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same thing too. Seems there might be a bug in the new beta 7/alpha 3 of Gradle, there's a bug report and it's been marked critical, so i'm hoping for a fix soon. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=204329

Comment: @oiZo Thank you for you reply, if you see any good news about it don't forget to post the solution here :)

Comment: I am also facing same issue.

Comment: If you are having the same issue, please go star the project in Google Code (the link above).

Comment: @oiZo : Done, let's see what happen ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image: comment the line in volley build.gradle]

I have faced same problem when I update the latest version.
I tried do this and success.

Comment: While commenting out that line in `build.gradle` will make the project compile, it does not solve the issue. With that 'fix' you won't be able to do automatic builds to bintray.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is `publishing` tag used in `bintray.gradle` of Volley project.
With Gradle 2.0.0 update its complaining about `publishing` can't be configured after it has been accessed.

For now commenting following line in `build.gradle` of `Volley` project will get the build going.

```
//apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

I will updted the comment once have better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't comment this line:

```
apply from: 'bintray.gradle'
```

just change these line of codes

```
publishing {
publications {
    library(MavenPublication) {
        groupId project.ext.group
        artifactId project.ext.archivesBaseName
        version project.ext.version

        // Release AAR, Sources, and JavaDoc
        artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/volley-release.aar"
        artifact sourcesJar
        artifact javadocJar
    }
}
}
```

to

```
    publishing.publications {
library(MavenPublication) {
    groupId project.ext.group
    artifactId project.ext.archivesBaseName
    version project.ext.version

    // Release AAR, Sources, and JavaDoc
    artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/volley-release.aar"
    artifact sourcesJar
    artifact javadocJar
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

publishing{ publications{}}, it's in the volley files you added to your project. Don't waste time looking in the project gradle.